# How do i use next connect package with next js 13

Tags: next.js, middleware, serverless, morgan, next-connect

I started an application with the latest version of Next Js and i tried to use next-connect to structure my routes because of things like middleware before routes which is how i did in version 12, here is a sample code

```js
import morgan from 'morgan';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { createRouter, expressWrapper } from 'next-connect';

const router = createRouter<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>();

// Logger middleware function
const loggerMiddleware = morgan('dev');
router.use(loggerMiddleware);

router.get((req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!');
});

export default router;
```

export default router
but it kept returning this error

```js
error Detected default export in '/Users/macuser/Desktop/code/new-next/app/api/fam/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.

- error No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/macuser/Desktop/code/new-next/app/api/fam/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
```